# Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class only on Android 3.2

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-manifest

I am developing an app that uses fragments with the support library. The app is working and is published, but i get this error report(Only with 3.2 OS versions):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.naviter.seeyou/com.naviter.seeyou.MenuDisplayActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
com.naviter.seeyou.DisplayFragment.onCreateView(DisplayFragment.java:57)
```

The Exception is thrown at the last line in the onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    if (container == null)
        return null;
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.Display);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_display, container, false); //here
}
```

and this is the xml file:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlAsDialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDisplayOk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="@string/Ok" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDisplayCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I repeat, that the app is runnig well, i got this exception only on few devices with Android 3.2 OS. And i'm importing fragment from:

> android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you have on line 19 in your xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing i solved the issue. 
I was accidentally extending the class with:

> DialogFragment

instead of:

> Fragment

And then using a custom layout for DialogFragment. Obviously this causes problems only on Android 3.2

I also find another problem later. In the Manifest i was using the theme Theme.DeviceDefault wich was added in android api level 14 and android 3.2 obviously can't live with this. Then i implemented a theme selector wich chooses the theme depending on the device API level.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing immediately apparent. I *have* seen crashes that report that as the primary stack trace with a "caused by" out of memory exception while it's trying to create a bitmap from a resource for the view it's inflating. Perhaps that's what's happening.